# What does n means in neural network neuron output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I've found this equation that explains the output of a neuron in a MLP network:

$y(n) = f(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x}(n) + b)$

I can understand the general context, but since i have no background with mathematical notation, i don't understand what the $(n)$ parameter means (e.g. $y(n)$, $x(n)$). Is it sort of a temporal or sample index? I've seen this notation in other machine learning subjects, but didn't find an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n is the dimension of the vector x and also y, as you can see wT is a transpose of w with dimension (n,n), is the image z is y and a is x. and dont bother about l it indicates the index of layer.

[image]

Comment: Is it mandatory to denote n? I mean, can i omit n and just write y or x?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but in the text i'm reading the author should've used $n$ as a temporal index because the dimensions of $y$ and $x$ are given in the text as follows: "[...] where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times 1}$, [...]"

Comment: yes u can omit n, however that K means the length of x

Comment: Thank you very much. I will accept your answer as correct.

Comment: is there any info about n, absolutly x(n) cant be a scalar, x(n) needs to be a vector.
However dont bother with it, try to understand the formula with the illustration. Happy learning

Comment: x is the input vector, but no information is given about (n). It could be a sample or temporal index. Since i'm writing a paper about this theme, i will just omit (n).